# PHP if condition: Logical operators for filter from a form

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm working with a form using the `<datalist>` tag, I have two input tags getting information from two different arrays. Below the form there is a Kanban board, the objective of the form is to serve as a filter, so when a user fills any of the inputs (or both) the board with fill accordingly.

Here is the problem: I had made two if staments (one for input) that work great when I use them alone but that I don't know how to put together because I don't know how to check which of the inputs has been filled (for that I believe I may have to use the `issset()` function), then if only one of them is used I need to use the `||` logical operator between them but if both are filled I need to use the `&&` operator.

Using this condition (`||` logical operator):

```
if (($tasksArray[$i]["responsible-party-names"] == $_POST['members'] && isset($_POST['members']))  ||
(($tasksArray[$i]['project-name'] == $_POST['projects'] && isset($_POST['projects']))))
```

If I fill only the `members` input it returns what it should.

If I fill only the `projects` input it returns all the projects in the array (although when using the if condition without the left part it works well).

Finally, if I fill `both` inputs I get the right project but all the team members.

What would be the simplest way to get it right?

**Update**:

This if condition it's inside the moveArray function, what comes after the if block looks like this:

```
{

$task = '<div id="item'.$i.'"'.'draggable="true" class="c-drag">';
$task .= '<div class="card cardTitle">'.$tasksArray[$i]['content'].'</div>';
$task .= '<div class="card cardDescription">'.$tasksArray[$i]['description'].'</div>';
$task .= '<div class="card cardProjectName">'.$tasksArray[$i]['project-name'].'</div>';
if (isset($tasksArray[$i]["responsible-party-names"])) {
    $task .= '<div class="card cardProjectResponsibleName">'.$tasksArray[$i]['responsible-party-names'].'</div>';
} else {
    $task .= '<div class="card cardProjectResponsibleName">'."Anyone".'</div>';
}

if ($tasksArray[$i]["due-date"] != "") {

    $task .= '<div class="card cardDueDate">'.date("d/m/Y", strtotime($tasksArray[$i]["due-date"])).'</div>';
}

$task .= '</div>';
 return $task;
}
```

Then I call the function on every part of the board (unassigned, to do, in progress, finished)

```
echo '<div id="board">';

echo '<div id="unassing">';
echo '<div id="unassing-bg" class="title">Unassigned</div>';

for ($i=0; $i < $tasksLenght; $i++) {
    if (isset($tasksArray[$i]['boardColumn']) === false) {
        echo(moveArray($i, $tasksArray));
    }
}
echo '</div>';


echo '<div id="todo">';
echo '<div id="todo-bg" class="title">To Do</div>';
for ($i=0; $i < $tasksLenght; $i++) {
    if (isset($tasksArray[$i]['boardColumn']) && $tasksArray[$i]['boardColumn']['id'] == "9805") {
        echo(moveArray($i, $tasksArray));
    }
}
echo '</div>';

echo '</div>';
```

And that produce sort of "a card" with data about a task in the corresponding place of the board.

Comment: You should have `isset()` first, otherwise you'll try to access the variable before checking whether it's set.

Comment: I think we are  missing some code that comes after the `if` block. Are you trying to do something with the POSTed members and projects?

Comment: @willoller Give me a moment and I'll update my question.

Comment: @willoller Now my code it's updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need the `isset` to come *before* trying to access the key on `$_POST` to prevent the "undefined" error.

I am assuming you have some code that looks like this:

```
$matchingTasks = [];
for ($i=0; $i <= count($tasksArray); $i++) {
    ...
}
return $matchingTasks; // or something
```

If that is the case, what you want is more like this:

```
matchingTasks = [];
foreach ($tasksArray as $task) {
    // Store your search values
    $members = isset($_POST['members']) ? $_POST['members'] : false;
    $projects = isset($_POST['projects']) ? $_POST['projects'] : false;

    // Store the search matches, only if you are searching by that key
    $members_match = $members && $task["responsible-party-names"] == $members;
    $projects_match = $projects && $task['project-name'] == $projects;

    // if you are searching for BOTH must match BOTH
    if ($members && $projects) 
        if ($members_match && $projects_match) {
            $matchingTasks[] = $task;               
        }
        continue;
    }

    // if you are searching for EITHER can match EITHER
    if ($members XOR $projects) {
        if ($members_match || $projects_match) {
            $matchingTasks[] = $task;
        }
        continue;
    }

    // if you are not searching match ALL
    $matchingTasks[] = $task;
}
return $matchingTasks;
```

---

More advanced, and would allow for more customization, is to stack these in a filter pattern like this:

```
$members = isset($_POST['members']) ? $_POST['members'] : false;
$projects = isset($_POST['projects']) ? $_POST['projects'] : false;

if ($members)
    $tasksArray = filter_by_members($tasksArray, $members);

if ($projects)
    $tasksArray = filter_by_project($tasksArray, $projects);

return $tasksArray;

//... elsewhere

function filter_by_members($tasks, $members) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($tasks as $t) {
        if ($task["responsible-party-names"] == $members) {
            $result[] = $task;
        }
    }
    return $tasks;
}

function filter_by_project($tasks, $project) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($tasks as $t) {
        if ($task["project-name"] == $project) {
            $result[] = $task;
        }
    }
    return $tasks;
}
```

This would let you stack new search filters, like `filter_by_id` or `filter_by_date` and by defining filter `function`s you can stack as many as you like without getting crazy with the logic.

Comment: While this will prevent the "undefined" warning, it shouldn't affect what results are returned.

Comment: I think he just wants the `either/or` case. But he claims that his code is processing *all* records.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I misunderstand the question.

Comment: Ah, I think what they are trying to make is a search functionality, so they can use either project name, project member, or both to find $tasks. I'll update my answer assuming that.

Comment: Yes, it is a search functionality. I was trying to implement your answer but looks like @Barman was right I'm still having the same results.

Comment: @NullEins try out the new answer, I think it matches what you are trying to do. If not, provide more code in the Question so we can see what you are trying to do and what you have tried already.

Comment: @willoller thank you for your answer, now my code it's updated

Comment: @willoller Hi, yes I'll do it. It's just that I'm haven't been able to implement it. As soon as I can I will do it. It's been a great guide, but I think my code is a little different from what you expected. I can't figure it out.